# Decompose $x^4 + x^3 + 1$ into irreducible factors over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

> Decompose $x^4 + x^3 + 1$ into irreducible factors over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

I think that the given polynomial is already irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, therefore the only irreducible factors are $x^4 + x^3 + 1$ and $1$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It is indeed irreducible. Maybe they want you to check that no irreducible polynomial of degree 1 and 2 divides $x^4 + x^3 + 1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, $x^4+x^3+1$ is irreducible. For it has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. And the only irreducible quadratic is $x^2+x+1$, which does not divide $x^4+x^3+1$.

Comment: Why it is sufficient to look for only irreducible quadratic polynomials (in this case $x^2+x+1$) and check if it divides $x^4+x^3+1$ and not also for irreducible polynomials of degree 1 and 3?